# registration form php shows empty field

Tags: php

Sir i am not except in php and i followed one tutorial and slightly modified   add some column and i followed inch by inch and when i test for  running  its  shows empty field what's i written wrong and i am using xampp php v 5.3.0

```
<?php    
include "db.php";

class Process extends Database
{
      public function verify_email($table,$email){
            //abc@gmail.com//
            $regexp = "/^[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/";
            if(!preg_match($regexp,$email)){
            return "invalid_email";
         }
         //Check email already exists or not
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM ".$table." WHERE u_email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if($count == 1){
                return "already_exists";
            }else{
                return "ok";
            }
        }


        public function insert_record($table,$input){
            $sql = "";
            $sql .= "INSERT INTO ".$table." ";
            $sql .= "(".implode(",",array_keys($input)).") VALUES ";
            $sql .= "('".implode("','", array_values($input))."')";
            $query = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
            $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->con);
            if($query){
                return $last_id;
        }
    } 
        public function send_activation_code($email,$act_code){

        }
}
$obj = new Process;

    if(isset($_POST["check_email"])){
       $email = $_POST["email"];
       echo $data = $obj->verify_email("user_info",$email);
       exit();
}

    if(isset($_POST["u_email"])){
    echo $name = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z]#i", "", $_POST["u_name"]);
    echo $age = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_POST["age"]);
    echo $dateofbirth = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_POST["dob"]);
    echo $gender = preg_replace("#[^a-z ]#i", "", $_POST["gender"]);
    echo $educationalqualification = preg_replace("#[^0-9A-Za-z ]#", "", $_POST["edq"]);
    $lang = $_POST["lang"];
    $count = COUNT($lang);
    $languages = "";
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $languages .= $lang[$i].",";
    }
    $languages = substr($languages, 0, -1);
    echo $languages = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z,]#i", "", $languages);
    echo $mobile  = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_POST["mobile"]);
    echo $whatsapp = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_POST["whatsapp"]);
    echo $pincode = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_POST["pincode"]);
    echo $district = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z]#i", "", $_POST["district"]);
    echo $states = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z]#i", "", $_POST["state"]);
    echo $country = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z]#i", "", $_POST["country"]);
    echo $others = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z]#i", "", $_POST["others"]);
    $data = $obj->verify_email("user_info",$_POST["u_email"]);
    if($data == "already_exists"){
        echo "Email Already Exists";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo $email = $_POST["u_email"];
    }
    echo $currentoccupation = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z]#i", "", $_POST["current"]);
    echo $workexperience = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z]#i", "", $_POST["work"]);
    echo $username = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z0-9]#", "", $_POST["username"]);
    echo $password = $_POST["password"];
    echo $repassword = $_POST["repassword"];


    //Start Validation from here
    if(empty($name) || empty($age) || empty($dob) ||  empty($gender) ||   empty($educationalqualification) ||  empty($languages) || 
    empty($mobile) ||  empty($whatsapp) ||  empty($pincode) ||  empty($district) ||  empty($state) ||  empty($country) ||  
    empty($currentoccupation) || empty($workexperience) || empty($username) || empty($password)){
          echo "empty_fields";
        exit();
    }

        if(strlen($password) < 9){
        echo "password_too_short";
        exit();
    }
    if($password != $repassword){
        echo "password_not_same";
        exit();
    }else{
      //hash password
        $options = array('cost' => 12,);
        echo $hash_password =  password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
    }
    $signup_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $act_code = time().md5($email).rand(50000,1000000);
    $act_code = str_shuffle($act_code);
    $user = array("u_name"=>$name,"dob"=>$dateofbirth,"age"=>$age,"gender"=>$gender,"edq"=>$educationalqualification,"languages"=>$languages,"mobile"=>$mobile,"whatsapp"=>$whatsapp,"pincode"=>$pincode,"district"=>$district,"state"=>$states,"country"=>$country,"u_email"=>$email,"current"=>$currentoccupation,"work"=>$workexperience,"username"=>$username,"password"=>$hash_password,"signup_date"=>$signup_date,"last_login"=>$signup_date,"act_code"=>$act_code,"activated"=>"0"); 
    $id = $obj->insert_record("user_info",$user);
    if($id){
        echo "Record Inserted Sucessfully";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: That email validation regular expression is completely wrong and will prevent a lot of people from registering at your site. All you can really do these days is check that there's an `@` in the address and if there is, attempt to deliver to the address. Things like `name@example.museum` exist, as do [international email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email) like `θσερ@εχαμπλε.ψομ`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: My advice: Stay *away* from "tutorials", especially the low-quality material floating around on YouTube. Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts and avoids ending up with confused concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: If email must be unique, the best way to enforce this is with a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column. The method used here is vulnerable to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: Do not use such a silly regexp to filter out emails. Among other thing you are rejecting all newer gTLDs with it... The left hand side is also completely wrong. You know you can have an address with a + in it?

Comment: Improved code formatting

Comment: Your `empty()` checks need to come before you try to access/manipulate the SUPERGLOBAL values.  Please walk away from this tutorial -- it is mega bad.  In fact, give us the link to it so that we can warn all future readers/watcher that it should not be used.